# Probability that 4 cards drawn from a deck of 52 cards are all hearts?

Tags: probability

Draw 4 cards from a deck. Determine the probability that all of them are hearts.

Will it be 1/13 * 1/12 * 1/11 * 1/10 ?

I'm not sure, any help will be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $13$ hearts in a standard $52$ card deck.

Probability is defined as $$\frac{\text{the number of favourable cases}}{\text{the number of possible cases}}$$

So, the probability will be $$\frac{13}{52}\cdot\frac{13-1}{52-1}\cdot\frac{13-2}{52-2}\cdot\frac{13-3}{52-3}$$

Answer (score 1):

The probability should be:

$\frac{13}{52}\cdot\frac{12}{51}\cdot\frac{11}{50}\cdot\frac{10}{49}$

Because everytime you draw a card the number of hearts diminishes and the total number too